# cloud-init smg in login screen

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, cloud-init

I am getting this SMG from cloud-init; with a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1

Capture

[image]
how Can I Fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem. It just happened when I rebooted the server. The login prompt is dead and the ssh connection timed out. I can only ping the server IP address. All suggestions of how to disable or uninstall Cloud-Init do not help as I cannot get in the box. Any special key combination to prevent the Cloud-Init from blocking the login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure getty@.service to wait until cloud-init.target has finished. Same concept as [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51805/systemd-messages-after-starting-login/), but waiting for network.target didn't work for me with the cloud-init messages.

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/
nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/cloud-init_wait.conf #anything ending in .conf
```

> [Unit]
>
> After=cloud-init.target

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, is there anything else you need to do after creating the file?

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked with me, as shown [here](https://www.networkreverse.com/2020/06/how-to-remove-cloud-init-from-ubuntu.html), just create an empty file, type :

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 on a Hyper-V machine. [Jeff's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1100913/1180576) *almost* worked for me. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161218/1180576) suggests creating the directory

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/
```

instead of

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/
```

The rest is identical. Create a `.conf` file inside this directory, add the contents

```
[Unit]

After=cloud-init.target
```

to it and reboot. That should do the trick.