# Ubuntu server after boot - cloud-init[892]

Tags: boot, server

After booting the VM with Ubuntu server 18.04.2
I get these extra lines printed in terminal...

[image]

Is there a way to hide those? So that it looks like this and stays so:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too got annoyed at this today as I was setting up Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 on Raspberry Pi.

I tried Jeff's solution from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080732/cloud-init-smg-in-login-screen), but that didn't work for me at first. After doing some more experimenting, I discovered that Jeff's solution almost works. But only if I create the directory `getty@tty1.service.d` instead of `getty@.service.d`, then his solution started to work.

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
```

This way it's also more in line with [systemd.unit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) manpages instructions too.