# cloud-init messages cluttering login screen in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, startup, cloud-init

I'm sorry to bring this up again as I know this question has been asked a few times before as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080732/cloud-init-smg-in-login-screen), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160012/ubuntu-server-after-boot-cloud-init892) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313232/boot-messages-in-login-screen-in-ubuntu-server-20-04).

These solutions have worked excellently for me right up until 22.04, but now despite following the same instructions I cannot get these messages to away, as shown in this screenshot:

cloud-init messages on login tty:

[image: cloud-init messages on login tty]

Has the configuration of cloud-init changed in 22.04? Is there another way to fix this?

To be clear, I don't want to disable cloud-init, I want its initialization to stop cluttering my login screen.

Comment: This was the sane on Ubuntu 20.04. I removed the service entirely..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable cloud-init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405442/how-can-i-disable-cloud-init)

Comment: Thanks guys, but I don't particularly want to disable cloud-init.  I know I don't need it, and that this is pedantry at its best, but I'd just like to duplicate the behaviour that seemed to work successfully on previous versions of Ubuntu.  After much messing around I found something that *appears* to work, however.  See below.

Answer (score 1):

So after much messing around and trying to wrap my head around the inner workings of systemd after reading [DigitalOcean's rather excellent guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files), I essentially tried the reverse of the previous recommendations.  Instead of instructing getty@tty not to start until cloud-init had finished, I asked cloud-init not to allow getty@tty to start until it had finished (if that makes sense).

In detail, this means I made a directory called cloud-init.service.d within which I made a .conf file that looks like this:

```
[Unit]

Before=getty@tt1.service
```

This appears to work, though in theory this should be logically equivalent to the previous solutions.  Anyhow I hope this helps others with the same problem.

Any further comments or clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: Good solution, if you indeed still want to have cloud-init running. 

Answer (score 0):

If you want *cloud-init* to run and to **not** write to the console then you can change the Systemd setting for `StandardOutput` for the *cloud-init* service files.

One method to do this is to create an override file.  This snippet will change the setting for the services `cloud-init-local.service`, `cloud-init.service`, `cloud-config.service`, and `cloud-final.service`.

```
for i in init-local init config final ; do 
  mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/cloud-${i}.service.d
  cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/cloud-${i}.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
EOF
done
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This might have negative consequences because the service files include the comment

> Output needs to appear in instance console output

I don't know why the output **needs** to be written to the console but the [commit history](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/commit/d1c6ad4a9bfaba86e101642330bd478d9badd361) says

> write stdout to tty so it shows up in GetConsoleOutput

`GetConsoleOutput` appears to be an Amazon EC2 call, so writing to console might be a way for *cloud-init* to provide information to users with cloud servers.

Comment: Thanks for that, very interesting and I'll keep it in mind.  Surely there's got to be a better way for them to get information to Amazon EC2 without writing to the actual tty1 console, but then I'm not a cloud computing expert so maybe not.

Comment: This doesn't help on 22.04