# Boot messages in login screen in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, init

I have quite bizarre issue after boot sequence, where boot messages continue on login screen and sometimes prevent from typing in user name. I've reinstalled few times, but issue persists. Is it to with the fact it installed on extended partition or something else?
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2946Q.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this does not prevent the user from logging in. You just type your username and password like you usually would. Fixing this is purely for aesthetics.

I fixed this by following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080732/cloud-init-smg-in-login-screen) on the same issue. In summary,

```
sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1/service.d
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1/service.d/cloud-init_wait.conf
```

Then insert the following lines into the `cloud-init_wait.conf` file.

```
[Unit]

After=cloud-init.target
```

This just forces the cloud-init service to complete loading before the tty login is allowed to start.